# Show error message in Flash alert Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

If I set a validation message up within my model

```
validates :name, :presence => {:message => 'The name cant be blank.'}
```

How do I get that message to show up in a flash alert, this is what i have tried so far

```
def create
   @message = Message.new(params[:message])
   if @message.valid?
     ContactMailer.send_mail(@message).deliver
     redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Thanks for your message, I will be in touch soon")
   else
     flash[:error] = @message.errors
     render :new
   end
end
```

but all i get is a black error message strip at the top of the page with no text in it, in my layout/application i have this

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
<div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
</div>
```

Any pointers appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not good idea to show validation errors through the flash message, but if you really need it:

```
flash.now[:error] = @message.errors[:name].first
```

You should use `flash.now[:error]` in case if you need to show message immediately.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-now
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: Thanks you, so if i wanted to have multiple error messages show would i do a separate call for each one?

Comment: Also you can use `@message.errors[:name].join(", ")` or `@message.errors.full_messages.join(". ")` for show all validation messages. But better show errors near the fields(this is more user friendly), use [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem, you can view examples in the docs.

Comment: yeah im going to put some js validation in, im just practicing with some server side stuff :)

Comment: Even better: `@message.errors.full_messages.to_sentence`